# How to host a public golang module not on github

Tags: go, github, module, repository

I'm an absolute newbie in golang, and I'm sure this is a newbie question. But having no luck finding a straight answer, and I suspect it is not me.

How exactly does the repository part of a module path map to an URL? All the examples on go.dev use github.com as the repository, but if I ever want to share a module I write, it won't be on github. Is it possible at all to publicly host elsewhere? (My non-golang projects are on sr.ht, and that would be my first choice).

Comment: https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Remote_import_paths

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reference to golang docs at [remote import paths](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Remote_import_paths), but I suspect, using your mention of sr.ht, you can just write

```
import "git.sr.ht/~user/repo.git/path/to/module"
```

The `.git` tells go that it will be looking at a git repository. Go will also try to use the `https` protocol first, so that does not need to specified.